# Possible bug in Refresh[x, None] on the very first x = val

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, evaluation, scheduling

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

> [CASE:3995912]

---

From `Refresh` docs:

> `Refresh[expr,None]` specifies that the value of `expr` should never automatically be refreshed.

```
ClearAll[z]
Dynamic[Refresh[z, None]]
```

You will see `z`.

Now evaluate `z = 2;`, then the value above will change from `z` to `2`, which is unexpected.

Evaluate `z = 4;`, this time `2` remains `2`, which is expected.

My interpretation is that updating is not handled with enough care on the first own value creation. Maybe not a major problem but I guess this flaw may lead to more subtle/hard to detect issues with Dynamic updating.

Is it a bug or have I missed something?

Comment: Clearly it is a bug. Adding the header and the tag.